# c# Datatable ( deleting Duplicate records within 60 seconds of each other , keeping only the first )

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a C# Datatable with three fields. Where I want to only keep the first records that were entered more than 60 seconds within the other similar records after that.

Similar being defined as:

Additional to the above  condition  the ID numbers and billing code must be the same to be excluded in the final table.

so my example below would be the input

|**IdNumber**(string)  |**EntryDate**(DateTime)|**BillingCode**(Int)|

|  5678                | 2021/06/16 08:46:37   |         56          |

|  5678                | 2021/06/16 08:46:54   |         56          |

|  5678                | 2021/06/16 08:47:16   |         56          |

|  5678                | 2021/06/16 08:47:54   |         56          |

|  5678                | 2021/06/16 08:47:59   |         57          |

|  5691                | 2021/06/16 08:47:59   |         57          |

|  5694                | 2021/06/16 08:48:00   |         57          |

And the resultant output should look like

|**IdNumber**(string)  |**EntryDate**(DateTime)|**BillingCode**(Int)|

|  5678                | 2021/06/16 08:46:37   |         56          |

|  5678                | 2021/06/16 08:47:54   |         56          |

|  5678                | 2021/06/16 08:47:59   |         57          |

|  5691                | 2021/06/16 08:47:59   |         57          |

|  5694                | 2021/06/16 08:48:00   |         57          |

I have struggled with this for the past day and cannot wrap my head around a solution.

Any suggestions either Linq or Datatable select queries will do?

Johan

Comment: LINQ to Objects doesn't provide this functionality easily in a built-in way, but MoreLINQ has a handy DistinctBy method: `list = list.DistinctBy(m => new { m.IdNumber , m.BillingCode});`

Comment: Hi This  creates the distinct list  for the  Id number and billing code but not for the transactions  less than 60 seconds apart , this is the part thats confusing me.

Comment: Do you need this to run on the database or can you bring all your records into C# memory first (in batches if required) ?

Comment: it is all contained in a c#  datatable  in memory.

Comment: the data is in memory within the c# application  , as a Datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Linq Query would be:

```
var toDelete =
    stuff.GroupBy(x => new { x.IdNumber, x.BillingCode })
        .SelectMany(g =>
            g.OrderBy(x => x.EntryDate)
            .Aggregate(
                new { toKeep = new List<Thing>(), toDelete = new List<Thing>() },
                (acc, record) =>
                {
                    var shouldDeleteRecord =
                        acc.toKeep.Any(x => x.EntryDate.AddSeconds(60) > record.EntryDate);

                    if (shouldDeleteRecord)
                    {
                        acc.toDelete.Add(record);
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        acc.toKeep.Add(record);
                    }

                    return acc;
                }
            ).toDelete
        );

// todo: delete your stuff here
```

The idea being, group them by IdNumber and BillingCode, then order them by Entry Date. Loop through each item in each ordered group, and keep the first one that's outside of the 60seconds boundary imposed by the last one. Delete the rest.

Would be much cleaner, and easier to maintain if you wrote it as loops instead of using just Linq though.

EDIT: sorry, forgot to say, I'm using `Thing` as a stand in for whatever your data is called:

```
class Thing
{
    public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
    public string IdNumber { get; set; }
    public int BillingCode { get; set; }
}
```

and `stuff` is an `IEnumerable<Thing>` (standin for your table).

Comment: Hi Callum When i try your suggestion in c: i get an error     "toKeep  does not exist in the current context" how do you declare and instantiate it.

Comment: i meant c# not c apologoes

Comment: @johan ah sorry, you might be using an older version of .Net/C#, I'll update my answer to change `(toKeep: new List<Thing>(), toDelete: new List<Thing>()), ` to `new { toKeep = new List<Thing>(), toDelete = new List<Thing>() },`. The syntax I was using in the original is called [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples). Came in C# 7.

Comment: @johan The Linq [`Aggregate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Aggregate__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____1_System_Func___1___0___1__) overload that I'm using takes a `seed` paramater, I'm instantiating `toKeep` as a property on an anonymous type as the seed.

Comment: Hi Callum looks lik i'm  getting positive  responses , need to check in more detail ...thank you for your support.

Comment: thank you Callum  your  post solved my problem , its working well